# #1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server weird message?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

So i have recently made a register PHP, I was just about to make a database but then this message occoured out of random:

```
Error

MySQL said: Documentation
# 1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

And then it told me to go to my config.inc.php, I got there and here's the info in it:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Now, as you can see. I'm connecting with 127.0.0.1, not localhost/phpmyadmin but 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin, I assure you that I doubt there's a problem with the config.inc, However this has happened since I installed wordpress org, But today I've noticed it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `localhost` instead of IP. `GRANT ALL on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'ROOT_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE' WITH GRANT OPTION;` -- that'll  fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does other connections to the MySQL server work?

I've seen in past this error in two occasions:

- The `mysql.user` table was completely empty providing no privileges at all. For example SUSE Studio produced such virtual machines at some point (maybe it's still the case, I did not check).
- You're missing `localhost` host in `mysql.user`. For MySQL `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are different - first one is for socket based connections, while the latter for TCP based ones.